# Question about forcing derivatives

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm here with another probably simple question. So I am taking derivatives of a function with respect to another variable not used in that function. So first I define that derivative

```
D[r[n, k, h, L, \[Mu]], lam] = v[n, k, h, L, \[Mu]], lam]/n
```

So this is all well and good but  then when I actually try to use that derivative in the context of another function, whoopsies it seems like mathematica has forgotten

```
In[773]:= D[3*r[n, k, h, L, \[Mu]], lam]

Out[773]= 0
```

So I checked if the original derivative is still defined and lo and behold

```
In[774]:= D[r[n, k, h, L, \[Mu]], lam]

Out[774]= v/n
```

(where v is the function of v)
How do I make mathematica do this pattern matching correctly? I'm sure this has been asked before but I didn't see quite where.

I thanks to daniel have figured that using

```
 D[f_ : 1 r[n, k, h, L, \[Mu]], lam] ^= v/n
```

Gives also the wrong answer in that
D[r[n, k, h, L, [Mu]], lam] gives the exact same answer as D[3*r[n, k, h, L, [Mu]], lam] which is obviously wrong

Edit: I am still unable to get this to work correctly so I've uploaded my notebook to git. You can find my full code here:
https://github.com/pjdog/mathematicaStuff/blob/main/danielsonderivatives.nb

Comment: First, your definition will not work, because it tries to assigne the rule to `D`  what is protected. You must use "UpSet": "^=". Further, MMA is a pattern matcher. If you want to match the pattern  "3*r[..]" you must say: `D[f_^ : 1 r[n, k, h, L, \[Mu]], lam] ^= v/n;`

Comment: Because I'm an uneducated caveman I just unprotect D before using it in that way lol. I definitelly shouldnt do it that way.

Comment: ALso the code you wrote does not work correctly Daniel. The first ^ keeps the code from running

Answer (score 3):

You can add the option `NonConstants -> {r}` to tell `D` that `r` does, indeed, depend on non-explicit variables. This is the best way, I think—then you can use all of `D`'s standard rules. Otherwise, you'd need to define pattern-matching to account for every single possible way `r` could occur in an expression, which is...a lot. (You could probably also replace `r` with an "internal" function which *does* explicitly depend on `lam`, but I'll take the `NonConstants` route here.)

But it's a bit finicky to get it to work as intended, especially when considering that you might have other nonconstants, and other variables with respect to which you might be taking the derivative.

(I'd also recommend using upvalues to associate the definition with `r` instead of `D`. I also recommend making the arguments patterns by appending a `_`, otherwise only the literal symbols `n`, `k`, etc. will work!)

Here, I check if you're taking the derivative with respect to any other symbols as well; if not, I give `v/m`, and otherwise I apply the $\partial/\partial\lambda$ derivative first, get `v/m`, and then take the remaining derivatives of that.

```
r /: D[r[n_, k_, h_, L_, \[Mu]_], p1___Symbol, lam, p2___Symbol, NonConstants -> {x___, r, y___}] :=
       Switch[Hold[p1, p2],
                Hold[], v/m,
                _     , D[v/m, p1, p2, NonConstants -> {x, r, y}]
              ]
```

One could repeat this sort of procedure to account for `n`th-derivative syntax and vector derivatives—let me know if that would be useful!

You also might want to add `r` as a nonconstant to *any* evaluation of `D`. This requires modifying `D`.

```
Unprotect[D];Clear[D];

Block[{r}, 

 D[expr_, p__, NonConstants -> {x___}] :=
   D[expr, p, NonConstants -> {x, r}] /; FreeQ[{x}, r, {1}];

 D[expr_, p__, NonConstants -> x_Symbol] :=
   D[expr, p, NonConstants -> {x, r}] /; !MatchQ[x, r];

 D[expr_, p : ((_List | _Symbol)..)] :=
   D[expr, p, NonConstants -> {r}]

];

Protect[D];
```

Let me know if you'd like me to explain anything I use here!

Comment: my defined derivatives are more complex than the ones I used in my example, and v is actually a function of the same variables as r.Additionally there are special derivatives of r wrt each of the variables because L and lam are related and those derivatives are geometric if that makes sense. I was attempting to figure out how to take the code you generously wrote and plug and play it to fix my code but as  have not figured out how to get it to function correctly. Mathematica is giving me the error that the Nonconstants -> {x.... y...) ] is too deep for an assigned rule to be found.

Comment: @PaulHughes ah, I see. That usually happens when the thing you're trying to assign upvalues to only occurs deeper than the first level of the expression. So, for example, `a /: f[a] := 1` will work, but `a /: f[g[a]] := 1` will give you that error. Here, even though `r` appeared deeper, the upvalue assignment to `r` succeeded because `r` was present as a head on the first level of the expression, namely as `D[r[...], ...]`. If you're not assigning derivatives to functions directly like that, you might have to add a definition to `D` after all!

Comment: Feel free, though, to edit your question to include the more general cases that are behaving badly, and I'll try to edit my answer to help out when I have the chance :)

Comment: also, replacing `v` with `v[n, k, h, L, \[Mu]]` (no underscores) should solve the first problem you mention!

Comment: hmm that's what I thought would fix it but I actually get the exact same problem as I describe above even if I directly copy your code, so now I don't think its actually the problem of th ecomplexity.

Comment: @PaulHughes you mean my code gives you that error? hmmm. copy-pasting my code to a fresh kernel, and adding the dependence on arguments for `v` works fine for me, no error messages. what version of mathematica are you in? and have you tried `ClearAll[r]` before evaluating?

Comment: @PaulHughes try `r /: D[r[n_, k_, h_, L_, \[Mu]_], p1___Symbol, lam, p2___Symbol, NonConstants -> spec_] := Switch[Hold[p1, p2], Hold[], v/m,  _, D[v/m, p1, p2, NonConstants -> spec]]`. What do you get then?

Comment: INteresting  when I clear r it works. I wonder if theres something that deals with already having defined r or attempting to make it a nonconstant before defining the derivative. I am on mathematica 12.0

Comment: I got TagSetDelayed::tagnf: Tag r not found in D[((1-h_^2-k_^2) (\[Mu]_/n_^2)^(1/3))/(1+Cos[L_] k_+h_ Sin[L_]),p1___Symbol,lam,p2___Symbol,NonConstants->spec_].  I wonder if it has to do with defining the vector as the derivative?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123629/discussion-between-paul-hughes-and-thorimur).